# matplotlib equivalent of Matlab's slice() function

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

What is the matplotlib equivalent of Matlab's [`slice()`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html) function for 4D plots. Please don't suggest `scatter`, it doesn't seem to work with `meshgrid(x,y,z)`.

Comment: matplotlib does not have such a function. Of course you can calculate the slice through the meshgrid with numpy and plot it on a [plot_surface](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots).

Comment: one way of looking at values of a function in "slices" of a 3D grid is the  [Axes3D.quiver](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html?highlight=quiver#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.quiver%20'Axes3D.quiver) which should actually work now in matplotlib 2.0 released last week

Comment: Here is an answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41914314/4285097