# How to visualize slices of volumetric data in matplotlib just as in Matlab?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can the [matlab function slice](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html?s_tid=srchtitle_slice_1) be replicated in matplotlib?

Consider the following piece of code from that page:

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2);
V = X.*exp(-X.^2-Y.^2-Z.^2);

xslice = [-1.2,0.8,2];   
yslice = [];
zslice = 0;
slice(X,Y,Z,V,xslice,yslice,zslice)
```

Please do not suggest any solutions that depend on vtk, mayavi etc as it seems that these cannot be installed on the system for reasons not important here.

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41914314/15521392 ?